# Fluent NHibernate one-to-one relation

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have table address and many tables for accounts.
How to write Fluent mapping one-to-one relation for this situation?

```
+----------+
| Address  |
+----------+
| Id       | PK
+----------+

+----------+
| AccountA |
+---------+
| Id       | PK
| AddressId| FK
+----------+

+----------+
| AccountB |
+---------+
| Id       | PK
| AddressId| FK
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's for auto mapping.

```
.Override<Address>(mapping => mapping.HasOne(address => caddress.AddressA).Cascade.All().LazyLoad())
.Override<Address>(mapping => mapping.HasOne(address => caddress.AddressB).Cascade.All().LazyLoad())
.Override<AddressA>(mapping => mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Address"))
.Override<AddressB>(mapping => mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Address"))
.Override<AddressA>(
     mapping => mapping.HasOne(
    Reveal.Member<AddressA, Address>("Address")).Constrained().ForeignKey().LazyLoad())
.Override<AddressB>(
     mapping => mapping.HasOne(
    Reveal.Member<AddressB, Address>("Address")).Constrained().ForeignKey().LazyLoad())
```

All this tables are had the same key: Id

```
+----------+
| Address  |
+----------+
| Id       | PK
+----------+

+----------+
| AccountA |
+---------+
| Id       | PK
+----------+

+----------+
| AccountB |
+---------+
| Id       | PK
+----------+
```